# comparar datos time con PHP y SQL

Tags: php, sql, time

Tengo que insertar una hora de comienzo y otra de finalización de una reunión.
Cuando inserto las horas por el post, tienen este formato:

HH:MM

Quiero compararlas con las que tengo guardadas en la BBDD, sin embargo, allí están guardadas como:

HH:MM:SS

Entonces, nunca coinciden. Necesito que en el post se añadan los segundos o que al recogerlos en la consulta no los tenga en cuenta para hacer la comparación.

Gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes extraer la hora en el formato HH:MM

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`time`, '%H:%i') AS `formatted_hour` FROM `table`;
```

Y posteriormente podrás compararlos así:

```
if(strtotime($time1) < strtotime($time2)) ...
```

Comment: y para extraer dos campos time? Tengo una hora de comienzo y otra de finalización. Necesito extraer las dos... Debo hacerlo en dos consultas o se puede hacer en una sola?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo en una única consulta, añade tantos TIME_FORMAT(`time`, '%H:%i') como necesites informando el nombre de la columna.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!